# How to make text input in table cell grow beyond the limits of the table when selected?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with three columns. A `label`, a dropdown selector, and an input field.

The input field is expected to contain multiple lines of content (specifically, `JSON`) but I do not want each row of the table to be tall. Instead, I want that when the user clicks on that cell, the content area should grow and flow over the boundaries of the table. When he blurs focus, it should shrink back to size.

Here's a JSFiddle I'm using to experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/xq704y5j/1/

Any ideas of how to do this simply in HTML, CSS? I'm also using Bootstrap already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xq704y5j/2/)

I added this css:

```
table{
    position:relative;
}
#sibiling-name1:focus{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

Hopefully that will get you headed in the direction you want to go.
-Ted

Edited to add:
See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xq704y5j/3/) for using a textarea instead of a text input.

Comment: that's awesome. I added a height property too, because I want it to be multi-line as I mentioned. The problem is that I guess an input element can't be multiline. So I tried a text area but the problem with that is that it's not a single line. I can't find the perfect combination

Comment: See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xq704y5j/3/). I used a textarea and set it's size, and it's size on focus.

Comment: Sure thing...if that does it for you be sure to 'accept' the answer. :)